# argument of type typeof '..' is not assignable to parameter of type 'router'. Property param is missing in type typeof ''

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I am developing a node app using a TypeScript in which I have written routing in a separate file 'route.ts'

```
import  home  =require('../controller/homeController');
import express = require('express');

let router = express.Router();

router.get('/',home.getIndex);

module.exports = router;
```

I have used this file in server.ts as

```
import route = require('./routes/route')
//routing api
app.use('/',route);
```

but while compiling it is giving me error

[image]

visual studio code is also showing me error

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript doesn't know about `module.exports` assignments. You should write `export = router` in route.ts instead.

Comment: export = router is not working for me still i'm getting same error

Answer (score 1):

For chain two route file in TS. I did like this:

app.ts file

```
app.use('/', index);
```

index.ts file

```
router.use('/users', users);
export = router;
```

users.ts file

```
router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    res.send('Get user: ' + id);
});
export = router;
```